# cmake linking error 2

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile a simple code using cmake and I getting an error. The code and cmake file are as below. The test.cpp is the main file in which i have directly included test1.cpp. I have also included my CMake file and the error that I am getting on performing make.

test.cpp

```
#ifndef _IOSTREAM_
#include<iostream>
#endif
#include"test1.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
printing("hello");
return 0;
}
```

test1.cpp

```
#ifndef _IOSTREAM_
#include<iostream>
#endif
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void printing(string s)
{
cout<<s<<endl;
return;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11)
add_executable(test test.cpp test1.cpp)
```

Error

```
CMakeFiles/test.dir/test1.cpp.o: In function 
printing(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >):
/home/vatsal/Desktop/test/test1.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition 
of printing(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >)
CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o:/home/vatsal/Desktop/test/test.cpp: 
(.text+0x0): first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target test failed
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target CMakeFiles/test.dir/all 
failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target all failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because include `cpp` file is a bad idea.

After preprocessor work you'll get two defenition of `void printing(string s)` The first one is in `test.cpp` because you've incleded `test1.cpp` and the second one is in `test1.cpp`.

Solution is to create `test1.h` which contain declaration of function:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void printing(string s);
```

Then fix test1.cpp:

```
#include "test1.h"
using namespace std;
void printing(string s)
{
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return;
}
```

And finaly replace `#include"test1.cpp"` with `#include"test1.h"` in `test.cpp`

Comment: thanks yes it works now but my doubt is why does it work when using terminal directly but does not work using Cmake?